# Moment JS: the right way to add # of days to the date in milliseconds

Tags: momentjs

In MomentJS library they give a way to add a number of days to the specific date:

```
//date math
moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').add(1, 'day').format('LLL')
"March 13, 2016 1:00 PM"
```

Is it possible to add the specific number of days to the date saved in milliseconds? 
I tried converting # of days to milliseconds and adding that number, but that would give me wrong date in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to get the expected result adding the number of milliseconds

```
moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').add(1, 'day').format('LLL')
'March 13, 2016 1:00 PM'
moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').add(86400000, 'milliseconds').format('LLL')
'March 13, 2016 1:00 PM'

moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').add(2, 'day').format('LLL')
'March 14, 2016 1:00 PM'
moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').add(86400000*2, 'milliseconds').format('LLL')
'March 14, 2016 1:00 PM'
```

With start date in milliseconds

```
moment(1457784000000).add(86400000*2, 'milliseconds').format('LLL')
'March 14, 2016 1:00 PM'
moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').add(86400000*2, 'milliseconds').format('LLL')
'March 14, 2016 1:00 PM'
```